# String manipulation in argument

Tags: c

I have got two functions. One function calls the print functions.
Calling function (`key` is a number between 0 and 42 symbolizing keys of a remote and the `keymap` just maps names to the keys):

```
void calling_function(int key){  
   print_info("[KEY]", ("%#4x %s", key, keymap[key - 1]));  
   ...  
}
```

And the printing function:

```
print_info(char *prefix, char *message){  
    print("%s %s\n", prefix, message);  
}
```

But the output looks like this:
`[KEY] COLOR_RED`

So the int is missing, why is it not inserting the integer? I would like to not work with `sprintf()`

Comment: Looks like you have confused C with some other language. Read about the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) for starters.

Comment: Actually I haven't. I was as well confused, why this does work in some way. I would just like to know why, and how to combine these variables in a string, without using sprintf

Comment: `sprintf` exists for a reason. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Well.. I see you're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the int is missing, why is it not inserting the integer?

Why would it?

> I would like to not work with `sprintf()`

Yet you seem to think that the expression `("%#4x %s", key, keymap[key - 1])` should be a shortcut.  It is not.  C does not have a Pythonesque syntax for string interpolation.  That's what `sprintf()` is *for*.  The expression you have used employs C's comma operator (`,`), which evaluates its left operand, discards the result, and then evaluates its right operand, returning that as the value of the expression.

Thus, your `print_info()` call is equivalent to

```
print_info("[KEY]", keymap[key - 1]);
```

(Note that the comma there is *not* a comma operator; it is part of the syntax of a function call.)

`sprintf()` is one of the standard ways to produce a formatted string, and it seems the most appropriate for this case.  You might approach it like this:

```
char message[KEYMAP_VALUE_LIMIT + 6];
sprintf(message, "%#4x %s", key, keymap[key - 1]);
print_info("[KEY]", message);
```

If you do not have and cannot reasonably create an appropriate `KEYMAP_VALUE_LIMIT` macro then you probably should dynamically allocate the `message` buffer based on the actual length of the string corresponding to `key`.  In this specific case, however, it looks like you could avoid that by redefining what is considered "prefix" and what "message":

```
char prefix[13];
sprintf(prefix, "[KEY] %#4x", key);
print_info(prefix, keymap[key - 1]);
```

Comment: If a need for this sort of thing is common in your application, then you might consider rewriting `print_info` as a varargs function (or creating a separate varargs version) built around `v[s]printf()`.  That's what *it's* for.

Answer (score 5):

The second parameter to `print_info` is `char *message`.  You've passed it `("%#4x %s", key, keymap[key - 1])` which knowing the comma operator evaluates to just the last item `keymap[key - 1]` which seems to also be a `char *` lucky enough.  You need to use some type of `printf` function to fill in the `printf` style format specifiers in `"%4x %s"`